# Enabling the Attributes column in Windows Explorer for a whole directory tree

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I need to see the Attributes column in all sub-folders of a certain directory. View->Choose Details and checking Attributes only seems to work for the currently selected folder. Can I enable this throughout, including for any subsequently created sub-folders?

(As can be done in the Choose Details dialog, I'd like to be able to specify the size and position that should apply to all folders as well.)

Answer (score 5):

Once you have enabled the attributes column and set its size:

- Go to Tools -> Folder Options-> View Tab
- Click the <kbd>Apply to Folders</kbd> button

That applies the view of the current folder to *all* the folders of a specific type though (not only the directory tree), but that's the only way I know of to basically do what you want.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but it doesn't appear to work for me on XP.

Comment: @djhowell: It works for me. That's actually one of the first things I do on a freshly installed system: set the explorer view on "details", add the attribute column and apply to all folders.

Comment: The actual button is "Apply to All Folders". And indeed it seems to effect all folders everywhere, not just the directory tree that I have in mind.

Comment: In Win7, start with Organize, then Folder and Search options, then the View tab.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the registry.  In **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced** add a DWORD called **ShowAttribCol** and set it to 1.

Comment: @djhowell, Will this show the Attribute column everywhere, not just the directory tree that I have in mind?